# Error connecting logic app to sap hana server using sap .net connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, sap-dotnet-connector, data-gateway

I want to connect sap to azure logic app ...

I have a sap server and via on-premise gateway and .NET connector 3.0  i am trying to create a SAP connection in Logic Apps using "SAP Application Server - Send to SAP" action but in vain !!

The error is like  :--
[Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: Unable to connect to SAP server. Failed to process request. Error details: 'Could not load file or assembly 'sapnco, Version=3.0.0.42, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50436dca5c7f7d23' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI2Cw.jpg)

Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some rules you need to compliance:

> 1. You need to install the 64 bit version and only the 64 bit of SAP Nco.
> 2. You need to install the latest version of SAP Nco as well.
> 3. You need to install the .Net 4.0 version of SAP Nco as the data gateway host service and Microsoft SAP Adapter are build with .Net 4.5.

For more details about with SAP Nco version to pick for Azure Logic App, you could refer to this [article](https://ittechnews.net/microsoft/official-microsoft-news/which-sap-nco-version-to-pick-for-azure-logic-apps-sap-connector/).

Also, someone gets the same error like you, he **download Nco connnector from SAP website** and **install in server** then everything goes well.
You could go to see the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/f5fd7103-66f7-41bb-8f97-88d7eeebb988/sap-connector-error?forum=azurelogicapps).

Answer (score 0):

I been have the same error. In my case have SAP in a private network and I use another machine with Data Gatewat to acces to SAP throught Logciapp.

This steps are not in SAP machine are in Midelware machine that will have Data Gateway to communicate with SAP.

> 1. Install Data Gateway
> 2. Install the SAP NCo library and .NET
> 3. Then for Data Gateway can recognize the SAP NCo library you will need to copy .dll located on SAP NCo folder installations to Gateway
>      folder installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some rules you need to compliance:

1. You need to install the 64 bit version and only the 64 bit of SAP Nco.
2. You need to install the latest version of SAP Nco as well.
3. You need to install the .Net 4.0 version of SAP Nco as the data gateway host service and Microsoft SAP Adapter are build with .Net 4.5.
   For more details about with SAP Nco version to pick for Azure Logic App, you could refer to this article.

Also, someone gets the same error like you, he download Nco connnector from SAP website and install in server then everything goes well. You could go to see the similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/f5fd7103-66f7-41bb-8f97-88d7eeebb988/sap-connector-error?forum=azurelogicapps).